# Bash Script - irsend LIST Output to JSON

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have this command:

```
irsend LIST lgtv ""
```

which outputs like this:

```
irsend: 00000000000010ef KEY_POWER
irsend: 0000000000008877 KEY_1
irsend: 00000000000048b7 KEY_2
irsend: 000000000000c837 KEY_3
irsend: 00000000000028d7 KEY_4
irsend: 000000000000a857 KEY_5
irsend: 0000000000006897 KEY_6
irsend: 000000000000e817 KEY_7
irsend: 00000000000018e7 KEY_8
irsend: 0000000000009867 KEY_9
irsend: 00000000000008f7 KEY_0
```

How do I grab each line and get the codes and key name and output them into JSON format?

EG:

```
[
    {"code": "00000000000010ef", "key": "KEY_POWER" },
    {"code": "0000000000008877", "key": "KEY_1" },
    {"code": "00000000000048b7", "key": "KEY_2" }
]
```

Comment: You can use the `jq` utilities to manipulate JSON in `bash` scripts.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON strings have to be in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: @Barmar just a concept, but see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AWK for your example:

```
irsend LIST lgtv "" | awk 'BEGIN{print "["}{{printf("{'"'"'code'"'"' : '"'"'%s'"'"', '"'"'key'"'"', '"'"'%s'"'"'}\n",$2,$3)}END{print "]"}'
```

The crazy `'"'"'` construct makes sure a `'` is actually output. Using double quotes is easier (and JSONier):

```
irsend LIST lgtv "" | awk 'BEGIN{print "["}{{printf("{\"code\" : \"%s\", \"key\", \"%s\"}\n",$2,$3)}END{print "]"}'
```

Comment: When you edit your answer, you don't need to keep the original, wrong code. Anyone who's interested can look at the edit history. It's not like editing a question, where the original code should be kept to maintain context with the answers.

Comment: @Barmar Accepted and fixed - I was just lazy.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is the -R command-line option, which allows lines to be read one-at-a-time. With your input, the following invocation produces the results shown (truncated):

```
$ jq -c -R 'split(" ") | {code: .[1], key: .[2]}' input.txt
{"code":"00000000000010ef","key":"KEY_POWER"}
{"code":"0000000000008877","key":"KEY_1"}
{"code":"00000000000048b7","key":"KEY_2"}
```

You might want to consider tokenizing the input string, e.g. if your jq has `splits/1`:

```
[splits(" +")] | {code: .[1], key: .[2]}
```

Notice that `splits/1` produces a stream, whereas `split/1` produces an array.

If you want the result as a single array, then you could pipe the above into `jq -s .`.